# Does global interpreter lock (GIL) still exist in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to find answer about this, but wasn't successful.

Comment: Yes it does, there are projects to remove it but they are not close to realisation yet

Comment: I should add my comment is specifically about the CPython interpreter (for all intents and purposes the default interpreter) other interpreters may or may not have a GIL

Answer (score 5):

The GIL was not removed in python 3. You can read more about it here https://realpython.com/python-gil/#why-wasnt-it-removed-in-python-3

[image]

Comment: I disagree with the part about "This was the reason why the early versions of Python 3 saw slower adoption by the community". Personally I believe the reason it was slow was due to the fact that Python 3 was syntactically incompatible with Python 2. It was also slower that the Python 2 interpreter. In other words, no gain for the pain...

Comment: @martineau  agreed about the "real" reason py3 has been long in the adoption.  On a separate "thread":  it would have been nice if the `gil` had been removed altogether. I do not like multithreading in python vs jvm languages